# jQuery var width not working on menus without dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Currently in the process of attempting to make a menu that has arrows beneath them when hover over occurs or when `.active` is added to the menu. All is good apart from the fact that it only works on the menu that has a drop down and also the childs of the parent also have the arrows which is something I do not want. Please [***visit my test site***](http://www.bournemouthcomputerrepairs.net/about-us/) if it makes it any easier to fault find using inspect.

Below is the example of what I want!

[image: Menu with arrow on active]

Below is what I do not want.

[image: Not working]

So as you can see above its missing the arrow which is strange because the services does but also on the child of services that I want to stop. So, two fixes are required.

CSS Code:

The CSS code uses absolute positioning and without `.active` it uses `opacity:1` meaning that the item is only viewable when a hover or click occurs.

```
.myribbon{
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:80px;
    height:0;
    width:100%;
    border-left:50% solid transparent;
    border-right:50% solid transparent;
    border-top:20px solid #ff9800;
    z-index:-1;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.myribbon span{
    height:80px;
    bottom:100%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    background:#ff9800;
}
.top-bar-section .active a .myribbon, .top-bar-section .active a:hover .myribbon{
    opacity:1;
    bottom:-20px;
}
```

JavaScript Code:

The script is suppose get the width of the menu item so that the arrow is the same width of the menu element.

```
(function($) {
  $('.myribbon').each(function(){
    var width = $(this).width();
    $(this).css({
      'border-left': width/2 + 'px solid transparent',
      'border-right': width/2 + 'px solid transparent'
    })
    $('span', this).width(width).css('left', width/2*-1);
  })
})(jQuery);
```

HTML:

Below is the HTML code without the JavaScript enabled. Whilst its enabled it fills in width values into the span but wrong values on menus other than services.

```
<header class="contain-to-grid">
  <nav data-topbar="" class="top-bar">
    <ul class="title-area">
      <li class="name"><h1><a rel="home" title="TEST SITE" href="">TEST SITE</a></h1></li>
      <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
    </ul>
    <section class="top-bar-section">
      <ul class="right">
        <li class="">
          <a href="/">
            <span class="myribbon" style=""><span style="width: 1140px; left: -570px;"> </span></span>
            Home
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-main-menu menu-item-services has-dropdown not-click" id="">
          <a href="#">
            <span class="myribbon"><span> </span></span>
            Services
          </a>
          <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="menu-item menu-item-main-menu menu-item-example-1" id="menu-item-19">
              <a href="#">
                <span class="myribbon"><span> </span></span>
                Example 1
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: i get no arrow at all (OS X / Chrome)...

Comment: @webeno the arrows is only working on the services page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ribbon is absolutely positioned and needs the parent to positioned relatively to be under the right menu.

For the dropdown the position is right

```
top-bar-section .has-dropdown {
 position: relative;
}
```

But for the other menu item it's not positioned relative. Add `position: relative` for the below selector

```
.top-bar-section ul li {
  float: left;
}
```

The above fix will also fix the width calculation issue automatically.

Comment: Awesome fix turn around. Thank You.